# Why do I get this error "Statement failed, SQLSTATE = 08001"?

Tags: firebird

When ever I try to connect with Firebird SQL I get this error,

```
firebird$ isql-fb 'db.FDB' -u SYSDBA -p <PASS>

Statement failed, SQLSTATE = 08001
I/O error during "open" operation for file "CAFW.FDB"
-Error while trying to open file
-Permission denied
Use CONNECT or CREATE DATABASE to specify a database
```

What can I do to resolve it, I've already ensured that my current user has read/write access to the file.

```
$ sudo chown firebird:firebird ./db.FDB
$ sudo chmod 770 ./db.FDB # should only need 660


$ ls -lah
-rw-rw---- 1 firebird firebird 53M May  2 17:13 CAFW.FDB
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your home is on an encrypted directory the daemon itself won't be able to read that home directory regardless of what the permissions are.

You feed `isql-fb` a filename, but that file isn't read by `isql-fb` but by `fbserver` which won't have access to an encrypted mount regardless of what the perms are.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add yourself in the Firebird group

```
sudo adduser `id -un` firebird
```

or always use localhost address in front of db if Server is Classic or SuperClassic

See the long thread here 
http://firebird.1100200.n4.nabble.com/Fwd-Have-you-tried-firebird-2-5-SuperClassic-from-the-packages-td3053790.html

Answer (score 0):

I have same mysterious problem with setup. OS is debian 11 arm64.  User is member of group firebird, but can only connect from isql-fb if run isql-fb as root user.
Prefix of file path with localhost: makes no difference.
Eventually I found that the database file had been created with owner as root:root, and required chown firebird:firebird